# Altermate to CURSOR - SQL

Tags: performance, sql

I am currently using an iterator because I have to insert record in one table, get its primary key and add it to another table. But since it's a loop, it's very slow when data is very big.

```
OPEN ITERATOR
Fetch NEXT FROM ITERATOR 
INTO @AccountNumber, @CardNumber, @ExpirationDate,
@CardHolderName, @CardToken, @CreatedDate, @Active, @CustomerId

While (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

INSERT into dev_NeoGateway_DTA.dbo.DTA_PaymentInstrument 
VALUES(@CustomerId, @CardToken, @CardHolderName, 0, '', 1, 0, @CreatedDate, 0, '', NULL)
SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT into dev_NeoGateway_DTA.dbo.DTA_CardInstrument 
VALUES(@newId, @CardHolderName, @CardNumber, @ExpirationDate)

Fetch NEXT FROM ITERATOR 
INTO @AccountNumber, @CardNumber, @ExpirationDate, @CardHolderName, @CardToken,
     @CreatedDate, @Active, @CustomerId

END
```

Comment: SQL Server, yes? Look up `output` clause to capture the new IDs to temp table or table valued variable, allowing multi row operations instead of the loop you have.